# Invertir número decimal en Java NetBeans

Tags: java, java-swing

Estaba intentando estudiar en esta cuarentena y me tope con esta duda. 
¿Cómo puedo invertir un numero decimal Double? 
Por ejemplo quiero invertir 12.54789 y el resultado sea 98.74521.
Con este fragmento de código he tratado de adaptarlo pero no funciona:

```
numDec1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número decimal : "));
//reul = reul * 10 + (numDec1 % 10);
cifra = numDec1 % 10;
reul = (reul * 10) + cifra;
```

¿Alguien me podrían ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución podría ser transformar el float a string y posteriormente realizar la inversa. Este código te proporcionaría el resultado esperado:

```
float num = 12.54789f;
String numString = String.valueOf(num);

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(numString);
stringBuilder = stringBuilder.reverse();

float reservedFloat = Float.parseFloat(stringBuilder.toString());
System.out.println(reservedFloat);
```

Comment: Si eso es una buena idea, muchas gracias por su tiempo.